# react-native run-android red screen of death

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]

appears after running `react-native run-android`

I click the reload JS button and it changes to

[image]

Which is more informative, I am using VS standalone Android Emulator, and have already ran `adb reverse etc etc`

I do not see an option for Debug server host & port for device in Dev settings like it says there should be.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you haven't set the server IP (which should be on the same local network as your phone).
From your question I assume you can connect to the emulator using `adb` then you should be able to send command to it using the following according to the [official guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html) pointed out by G. Hamaide:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

This should send *open menu event* to the emulator and show you the menu where you will find `Dev Settings` and if you open it there you will find `Debug Server host & port`.
In order to connect to this server you must be on the same local network (i.e. connected to the same router). I assume you are using default options on a Windows machine so open a cmd shell and learn you local IP address using `ipconfig`. You can now set host and port to YOUR_LOCAL_IP:8081 (default port is 8081). Try to reload and it should work now.

Answer (score -1):

You need to follow the steps from their [official guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/running-on-device-android.html#content).

From where you are stuck follow these steps :

1. Open the Developer menu by shaking the device or running adb shell input keyevent 82 from the command line.
2. Go to Dev Settings.
3. Go to Debug server host for device.
4. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081). On Mac, you can find the IP address in System Preferences / Network. On Windows, open the command prompt and type ipconfig to find your machine's IP address (more info).
5. Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.

Comment: I did that, no dice , i did all the things the red screen of death suggested before posting